# Google charts: Combo charts - How to overlay 2 bar charts. One on top of the other

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a google combo chart that displays a column bar chart and a line graph on top of it.  Pretty simple.  Examples on the google charts site.

Daily amount(column/bar chart)
Current amount(line graph)

What I want to do is add Expected amount bars behind the current Daily amount bars.  Keeping everything else the same.  So a person can at a glance see how close they came to the expected amount. How can I do this in google charts. I just want to overlay one bar chart on top of the other basically, daily on top of expected, but can't find any info on this.  Thanks for any help, new to this.

Comment: In doing a little more digging I think maybe a diff chart is in order? Again new to this, so want all options. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to old, but just to give a closure because it also pointed me to get the answer.

To achieve what you need, definetly you need combo charts
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

This documentation has everything you need, but check specifically for the "Series" section, which allows you to configure the overlay and the type of each chart to be overlayed.